# SSO setup with Microsoft Identitiy using msal-browser & msal-react

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular, msal-react

I am implementing SSO in React SPA with Microsoft identity & using "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.5.0" & "@azure/msal-react": "^2.0.7" as dependency.

Please refer the below sample app provided by Microsoft:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-react-samples

```
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";

const { instance } = useMsal()

let loginRequest = {
  scopes: ["user.read", "mail.send"]
}

const handleMSLLogin = () => {
 instance.acquireTokenPopup({ loginRequest }).then(response => {
  console.log(response) //This response contains JWT token with client information and is visible in network calls
})
 .catch(e => {
   console.log(e)
  })
 }
```

**My question, is it safe to use this implementation ? **

I am able to authenticate user with recommended authorization code flow but it seems this has security threat as JWT token returned is visible in network calls

Comment: Please see below response from Microsoft : 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1427553/is-is-safe-to-use-msal-browser-on-production?page=1&orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1365433